# Problema com rotas no laravel

Tags: laravel-5, route

Tenho slugs armazenados na base de dados de diferentes tabelas, eu pretendo usar a url sempre assim `www.exemplo.com/slug`.
Para isso eu criei uma única rota para isso que ficou assim:

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'SlugAppController@view');
```

Essa rota redirecciona para um `controller` onde estou a tentar fazer a validação se quando a pessoa carrega numa categoria mostra `view` categorias, se for um utilizador mostra a `view` perfil do user.

O que esta acontecer e que quando carrego numa categoria mostra a categoria bem sem problemas, mas quando acesso a um utilizador apresenta o seguinte erro.

> ErrorException in SlugAppController.php line 24:
>   Trying to get property of non-object
>   in SlugAppController.php line 24

Linha 24 corresponde ao `if ($result_categorias->slug == $slug)`

esse erro acontece quando estou a tentar aceder a um utilizador `www.exemplo.com/cesar-sousa` esse slug existe na base de dados.

Pelo que percebo do erro ele retorna como null no `if ($result_categorias->slug == $slug)` que e das categorias, acho como estou a tentar aceder a um utilizador ele nem devia entrar no primeiro `if` mas não sei conto com a vossa ajuda para resolver isto.

**Controller**

```
public function view (Request $request){

    $slug = $request->slug;

    $result_categorias = DB::table('colecoes')->where('activo', '=', '1')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
    $result_users = DB::table('users_social')->where('activo', '=', '1')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    if ($result_categorias->slug == $slug) {
        return self::estabelecimentos($request, $slug);
    } else if ($result_users->slug == $slug) {
        return self::perfil($request, $slug);
    } else {
        return redirect('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Posta o erro completo `Trying to get property of non-object`, tipo linha e arquivo, da maneira que está não tem como termos certeza.

Comment: Já coloquei o link que coloquei no fim tem todo o erro que apresenta

Comment: Isto não é o erro todo, é o caminho do Exception, o erro é apenas isto `ErrorException in SlugAppController.php line 24:
Trying to get property of non-object
in SlugAppController.php line 24`, vou editar a pergunta

Comment: Qual linha é a 24?

Comment: O que tem na linha 24?

Comment: coloquei na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso `$result_categorias->slug` está retornando `NULL`, por isso o erro é gerado.

Provavelmente, algum outro fator está fazendo com que o Laravel não encontre esse `$slug` no banco.

Note que, quando você usa `first`, você tem dois possíveis retornos: O objeto contendo o resultado, ou `NULL`.

É isso que está ocasionando tal erro.

Até onde eu sei, você poderia capturar o valor vindo de `$slug` através do parâmetro da função, e não da variável `$request`.

Veja:

```
function view(Request $request, $slug) 
{
     $result = DB::table('minha_tabela')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
}
```

Sugiro também que, se for usar `first`, utilize `isset` antes ou `is_null` para checar  se o valor não é `NULL` no contexto, pra evitar erros.

Percebo também que o seu código há um pequeno problema de lógica: Se eu faço um `where` pra saber se o `$slug` está no banco, porque preciso verificar de novo no `if`? Isso não faz sentido! Se não existir o `$slug`, simplemente retornará `NULL`.

Mude seu código para:

```
public function view (Request $request, $slug) {


    $result_categorias = DB::table('colecoes')->where('activo', '=', '1')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
    $result_users = DB::table('users_social')->where('activo', '=', '1')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    // Se não for NULL, é porque é o slug capturado acima
    if ($result_categorias !== null) {

        return self::estabelecimentos($request, $slug);
    } else if ($result_users !== null) {

        return self::perfil($request, $slug);

    } else {
        return redirect('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: E como resolvo então

Comment: Bem notado a questão das `ifs`, olhando melhor o código minha sugestão iria falhar de qualquer forma, pq em ambos casos causaria `notfound`, a não ser que houve-se slugs iguais em ambas tabelas. +1

Answer (score 2):

Isto deve estar retornando `null`:

```
 $result_categorias = DB::table('colecoes')->where('activo', '=', '1')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
```

Pois se acessou a URL como `www.exemplo.com/slug`, então ele deve estar procurando algo no banco assim:

```
... WHERE ativo=1 AND slug='slug'
```

Se não existir no banco ele retorna `null` mesmo, o que você pode fazer é tratar a página, tipo uma página de erro 404, basta trocar `first` por `firstOrFail`

```
$result_categorias = DB::table('colecoes')->where('activo', '=', '1')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();
$result_users = DB::table('users_social')->where('activo', '=', '1')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();
```